# Google and primary domains

Tags: google, domains

I have a client's website that was previously on a domain, let's say craigaccounting.com, and now this will not be used as their primary domain. I want their primary domain to be cragaccountants.com, with the old domain just pointing to the new.

At the moment, Google is listing craigaccounting.com as the domain, but I want this changed. I have submitted the new domain with webmasters - is this all I need to do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Google is listing"? Is this in a search? For what words?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a 301 permanent redirect from the old domain to the new one. See http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=83105

Comment: Mmmm... it's not so much a site move though, the old domain is pointed to the new one anyway, I simply want the listing in Google to be craigaccountants.com. The issue of 404ing doesn't apply.

Comment: The 301 redirect tells google the new domain should be used and the old one should no longer be used. This is definitely the way to do it. It's also helpful for anyone who finds the old URLs as it automatically takes them to the new URLs.